# Javascript - Recursive Iterator Needed for data Restructure - Having a hard time nesting

Tags: javascript, recursion

thanks for your time for anyone that has dealt with such a problem again.

I am parsing some YAML data, and for sake of clarity i keep them named and as much without arrays as possible.

This results into JSON with named keys. I have already implemented the rest of the code i need (it's for a search function). For which the requested now function was bypassed by just manually creating JSON (huge) code for testing purposes.

But now I require the iterative option.

If anyone know how to deal with this i thank you very much.

Here goes:

```
var data = [{
    "a_1": [{
            "a_1_1": [
                "a_1_1_2",
                {
                    "a_1_1_2_1": [
                        "a_1_1_2_1_1"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "a_1_2": [
                "a_1_2_1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}];
```

And the result should be "innified":

```
var data_innified = [{
    "name": "a_1",
    "inner": [
        {
            "name": "a_1_1",
            "inner": [
                {
                    "name": "a_1_1_2",
                    "inner": [
                        {
                            "name": "a_1_1_2_1",
                            "inner": [
                                {
                                    "name": "a_1_1_2_1_1",
                                    "inner": null
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "a_1_2",
            "inner": [
                {
                    "name": "a_1_2_1",
                    "inner": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];
```

If it is possible an iterator without jquery, if possible in ES5
Providing a recursive function seems pointless since anyone who has dealt with such functions can easily put one together. The problems start later on....

I also tried to deal with this by json.parse revivers without much luck since the object gets populated by duplicate, original-named keys and "name": original-name key-value.

Thanks to anyone who could help. (Always spend many hours with recursion, but this one is just beating me silly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you

```js
var data = [{
  a_1: [{
      a_1_1: [
        "a_1_1_2",
        {
          a_1_1_2_1: ["a_1_1_2_1_1"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      a_1_2: ["a_1_2_1"]
    }
  ]
}];

function createObject(obj) {
  if (!obj) {
    return null;
  }
  if (typeof obj == "string") {
    return {
      name: obj,
      inner: null
    };
  }
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  if (!keys.length) {
    return obj;
  }
  if (keys.length == 1) {
    if (isNaN(Number(keys[0]))) {
      var output = {};
      output["name"] = keys[0];
      output["inner"] = createObject(obj[keys[0]]);
      return output;
    } else {
      return createObject(obj[keys[0]]);
    }
  }
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(Number(keys[i]))) {
      var output = {};
      output["name"] = keys[i];
      output["inner"] = createObject(obj[keys[i]]);
      arr.push(output);
    } else {
      arr.push(createObject(obj[keys[i]]));
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(createObject(data));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works very well. Have a great week!